# Comnbobox not coming up in datagrid binded to datatable

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, datatable

I have DataTable  like this

```html
            var uiPivotTable = new DataTable();
            uiPivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(string)));
            uiPivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
            uiPivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pass", typeof(bool)));
            uiPivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("subject", typeof(IEnumerable<string>)));
```

I have a column of type bool and another column of type IEnumerable.

I am assigning this datatable to datagrid with AutoGenerateColumns="true".
I am seeing check boxes for bool type. I expect Combobox to be shown for IEnumerable type. But its not happening.

Am I missing something here?

How do we show combobox in this scenario for each row for column subject?

Answer (score 0):

What if you do:

```
uiPivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("subject", typeof(List<string>)));
```